# Cannot find CatalogManager.properties using Saxon from command line

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have installed saxon and saxon-scripts on Centos 7 (using yum) in order to be able to perform some XSLT transformations on a remote server.

On my local machine (a Mac), doing:

```
saxon -xi -o:/path/to/transformed.xml /path/to/original.xml /path/to/transformation.xsl
```

works without a hitch. The same command on Centos gives me:

```
Cannot find CatalogManager.properties
```

I have looked at both [Running XSLT from the Command Line](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!using-xsl/commandline) and [Using XML Catalogs](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!sourcedocs/xml-catalogs) from the Saxon Documentation but the explanations there are way above my pay grade.

Is it possible to ignore this catalog manager business and perform the transformation from the command line without it? How would one go about it?

Comment: Do you get that error when trying to run any XSLT against any XML with Saxon? Or only with some particular XSLT and/or XML? Have you tried the normal options like `-s:/path/to/original.xml -xsl:/path/to/transformation.xsl`? I am not sure what that "saxon" command/shell script(?) does exactly, it might help to show us its code as the normal use of Saxon is just with `java ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what saxon-scripts does, or why it's going wrong, but I suggest you bypass it and invoke Saxon directly: write

```
java -cp:(classpath) net.sf.saxon.Transform -xi -o:/path/to/transformed.xml 
  -s:/path/to/original.xml -xsl:/path/to/transformation.xsl
```

where (classpath) is the directory in which the saxon JAR file is installed.

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course. Running `java -cp /usr/share/java/saxon.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -xi -o:/path/to/transformed.xml /path/to/original.xml /path/to/transformation.xsl` did the trick. Many thanks!